# What is the meaning of hidden_dim and embed_size in LSTM?

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to learn RNN and LSTM. I cam across a tutorial for sentiment analysis. Below is the code I in the tutorial where word2idx is a dictionary with word to index mapping

```
    class SentimentNet(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, vocab_size, output_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers, drop_prob=0.5):
        super(SentimentNet, self).__init__()
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers, dropout=drop_prob, batch_first=True)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(drop_prob)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_size)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

     vocab_size = len(word2idx) + 1
     output_size = 1
     embedding_dim = 400
     hidden_dim = 512
     n_layers = 2
```

Can anyone please tell me the meaning of vocal_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recurrent neural network (LSTM), at its most fundamental level, is simply a type of densely connected neural network.

The hidden dimension is basically the number of nodes in each layer (like in the Multilayer Perceptron for example)

The embedding size tells you the size of your feature vector (the model uses embedded words as input)

[here some details](https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-are-word-embeddings/)

Comment: @user11619814 you're welcome. Don't forget to accept the best answer :)

Comment: input_dim = 5,hidden_dim = 10,n_layers = 1, lstm_layer = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers, batch_first=True), batch_size = 1, seq_len = 3, inp = torch.randn (batch_size, seq_len, input_dim), hidden_state = torch.randn(n_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim), cell_state = torch.randn(n_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim), hidden = (hidden_state, cell_state), out, hidden = lstm_layer(inp, hidden), print(out)

Comment: so in the above code the input is [1,3,5] and output is [1,3,10] which means there are 3 outputs corresponding to the input length. If we want output at each time step we access the last output in the sequence, so I want to know what does the 1st and 2nd output correspond to? What meaning do they have?